# How to add Jar to Submodule in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, jar

I create a proyect in Android Studio, and I have a submodule where all logic it's done, I try to add a .jar but it don't work I get an error, but Android Studio don't show any error until I try to execute and compile.

This is the error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: es/uam/eps/multij/Tablero
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.uam.eps.multij.Tablero
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

BTW:if I extract the jar and create a package with the same path it works.

This is the gradel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjZ4a.png

Comment: I can't fix it and anyone of my classmate colud.
Finally I decided not created submodules, and use packages as modules, Thats works

Comment: Check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?rq=1
For a best answer.